# Is the /explode cheat real

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was looking up cheats for minecraft and found a cheat that exploded yourself `(\explode)` Next time I played I tried it and it didn't work all it said was `Unkown command. Try /help for a list of command` 
Is this part of vanilla minecraft or is it part of a mod. If it is then what mod?

Comment: Ok just edited your post with some grammar cleaning and put explode in grey(Hint:use ` at the beggining and end of where you want it and it is located on the top left of the keyboard under ~)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\explode` is part of the [CommandBin Mod](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/commandbin/pages/v3-0-commands-and-permissions/) as well as [SinglePlayerCommands](http://singleplayercommands.wikispaces.com/) (and potentially others).  This command is not in vanilla Minecraft.

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWOpPWYjjxY) of the Single Player Commands version.

Comment: Why the down votes

Comment: @Thegamer I did not downvote it, but my guess would be that your question comes across as showing a lack of research.  After all, you mention that you looked it up, so wherever you found it should mention where it is from.  Also, asking what mods contain `\explode` is borderline list question.  I can only theorize, though, so you might think of asking in [meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/) if you would like to improve future posts.

Comment: How do you make the grey background for the \explode thing

Comment: @thegamer Put ` around it. You can join the formatting playground [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/716/42984)